# What f() for unscented kalman filter for stock trading?

Tags: matlab, kalman-filters

I am trying to estimate to "next" price of a stock, based on a group of 5 other correlated stocks.

I believe this is a 6 state unscented Kalman problem. However, I do not know how to describe `f()`. I am measuring the "price" of the stock at end of day. i.e. I get one price per stock per day, and I have a set of 6 stocks.

Here `f()` is the deterministic part of the state update equation in the unscented Kalman filter :

```
x_k+1 = f(x_k) + w_k
```

[which is implemented here.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18217-learning-the-unscented-kalman-filter/content/ukf.m)

I wish to estimate tomorrow's EOD price for stock A, based on an UKF that considers stocks B-F as well. But I don't not need to estimate stocks B-F.

What might `f()` look like?

Comment: Isn't this the million dollar question (pun intended)? As you noted, your `f()` would represent the deterministic state transition from one time step to the next. Stated differently, given the stock prices at the end of day `k`, how will those prices change on day `k+1`? I would assert that there's unlikely to be any deterministic component; if there was, then you could use that knowledge to make risk-free profit; the stochastic component is zero-mean, so its effect on your trades should average to zero over time (barring the usual concerns of a really bad trade that bankrupts you).

Comment: You are quite right of course. However, if I use f=@(x)x(); - then I get a result. My question is if anyone has something better.

Comment: It's possible that someone does, but if they did, they would be best served keeping it to themselves. This is why it's hard to find a lot of open-source information on automated trading algorithms: if everyone knows them, they are unlikely to be profitable in an efficient market. Hence, that information is typically kept proprietary.

Comment: Related info: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/kalman-filter-equity-example